# Why add_library() creates a codeblocks project instead of a .a file?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a static library via CMake. I have this CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Test VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(Test main.cpp library.cpp)

add_library(MyLib STATIC library.cpp)
```

where library.cpp contains one function.
When I hit the build button, I find a Test.cbp file in one of build folders. Why isn't it a `.a` library? I'm using MacOS.

Comment: "I find a Test.cbp file" - So you find a **project** file, which is created by the `project` call, not by the `add_library` one.

Comment: CMake doesn't generally build your code.  It just generates configurations for other build systems (like make, visual studio, etc) to do the actual building.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see. Then where is my library supposed to be located? There's not a singe .a file in my project. I checked.

Comment: Have you **built** your project? Exactly on that stage library and executable files are created. *Configuration* only creates a project file(s).

Comment: @Tsyvarev sure thing! I built the project, and there were no warnings/errors.

Comment: Did you hit the build button on the `Test` executable which does not depend on `MyLib` in any way?

Comment: @AlexReinking no, I built the entire project in CLion, just as I usually do. After this they usually appear in my project files.

Comment: By the way, I tried assembling a library on blank new projects, and it worked. Although I can't find any differences or reasons of why it doesn't build anything in this particular case...

Comment: I remember that some build tools for CMake don't like executables/targets named in the same way as the project. You executable has the **same name** as the project: `Test`. I would suggest to rename one of them.